# Extract the list of public methods of a class separately using Doxygen

Tags: c++, github, markdown, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for my C++ project which will be hosted in github.

I want to include the list of methods of a class in the readme file and I am thinking of ways to automate it.

I will include the entire generated html pages in the repo, but thought it would be nice to give an idea of the API, by including the members of the main class in the readme file.

So far I couldn't find a way to generate markdown files. My next idea was to write some shell script that will automatically copy the member list and included it in the readme file and for that I need to generate the list of member functions of a class separately.

Is it possible to configure doxygen to just output the list of members of a class separately?

Answer (score 4):

I had a project recently where I wanted to identify several functions as part of the public API. I did not feel the need to put them in a README file so what I did is not really what you are after but you may find it a potential compromise.

I created a group with:

```
/**
\defgroup public_api Public API
\brief This is a list of the primary functions that comprise the
public API.

*/
```

Then I referenced it on the mainpage:

```
/**

\mainpage Some Project

...

See \ref public_api "Public API" for details on these functions.

*/
```

Then I explicitly marked each public API function as being in that group.

```
/**
\brief Perform any necessary initialisation before processing.

\ingroup public_api

This function must be called prior to any of the other public
api functions to allow initialisation to be performed prior to use.


 */
void init();
```

The net result is a list of the functions on a single page that is linked to from the main page. I know this is not exactly what you are after but I kind of like that doxygen brings all the documentation into a single place that is easy to navigate around.

If you do solve the problem to your satisfaction, please post it. I am always interested in atypical uses of doxygen.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. Let me try it out. If I don't get any other answers, I will select this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the list of members of a class from doxygen [XML output](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#xmlgenerator) . Setting `GENERATE_XML` to `YES` in the config file, generate xml files that look like this:

**xml/classTest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<doxygen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.7.6.1">
<compounddef id="classTest" kind="class" prot="public">
<compoundname>Test</compoundname>

  <sectiondef kind="public-func">

      <memberdef kind="function" id="classTest_1a99f2bbfac6c95612322b0f10e607ebe5" 
         prot="public" static="no" const="no" 
         explicit="no" inline="no" virt="non-virtual">

         <type></type>
         <definition>Test::Test</definition>
         <argsstring>()</argsstring>
         <name>Test</name>
         <briefdescription>  </briefdescription>
         <detaileddescription>
               <para>A constructor. A more elaborate description of the constructor. </para>        
         </detaileddescription>
         <inbodydescription>  </inbodydescription>
        <location file="/home/davidl/SO/test.cpp" line="23"/>
      </memberdef>

  </sectiondef>
</compounddef>
</doxygen>
```